# Is dot product and normal multiplication results of 2 numpy arrays same?

Tags: python, numpy, dot-product

I am working with kernel PCA in Python and I have to find the values after projecting the original data to the principal components.I use the equation

```
 fv = eigvecs[:,:ncomp]
    print(len(fv))
    td = fv.T * K.T
```

where K is the kernel matrix of dimension (150x150),ncomp is the number of principal components.The code works perfectly fine when fv has dimension (150x150).But when I select ncomp as 3 making fv to be of (150x3) as dimension,there occurs error stating operands could not be broadcast together.I referred various links and tried using dot products like
  `td=np.dot(fv.T,K.T).`
I dont get any error now.But I dont know whether the values retrieved are correct or not...

Plz help...

Comment: Are `fv` and `K` `numpy` arrays, or the `matrix` subclass?

Comment: fv and K are numpy arrays...I got  <type 'numpy.ndarray'> as the types when I print the type of fv and K..

Comment: Without knowing more about the underlying task we really can't say whether a element by element multiplication or dot (matrix product) is the right one.  The 1st requires matching dimensions all around, the 2nd matches the last and first dimensions.

Comment: @hpaulj ..but the code works fine when the dimensions are(150x150)*(150x150) in KPCA and when (3x4)*(4x150) in PCA....I dont know how....

Comment: Square arrays work with either type of multiplication.  The other looks like a `dot` product, producing a `(3,150)` array (the size 4 dimension disappears under summation).

Comment: @hpaulj: sorry I didnt get you fully..I have found what my arrays do is elementary multiplication dimensions as mentioned before...but  the value error comes(mentioned before)..

Comment: Have you worked with this in MATLAB as well? If so, add that code. You seem to be confusing `*` with `.*`

Answer (score 3):

The `*` operator depends on the data type. On Numpy **arrays** it does an element-wise multiplication (**[not the matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)**); `numpy.vdot()` does the "dot" scalar product of two vectors (which returns a simple scalar result)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1,2,3]])
>>> np.vdot(x, x)
14
>>> x * x
array([[1, 4, 9]])
```

---

To multiply 2 arrays as matrices properly, use `numpy.dot`:

```
>>> np.dot(x, x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: objects are not aligned
>>> np.dot(x.T, x)
array([[ 1,  4,  9],
       [ 4, 16, 36],
       [ 9, 36, 81]])
>>> np.dot(x, x.T)
array([[98]])
```

---

Then there is [`numpy.matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html), a specialization of array for which the `*` means **matrix multiplication**, and `**` means matrix power; so be sure to know what datatype you are operating on.

---

The upcoming Python 3.5 will have a new operator `@` that can be used for matrix multiplication; then you could write `x @ x.T` to replace the code in the last example.

Comment: :Thnku for the fast response.!...So what can I do to rectify the error?How can I multiply (3x150 ) * (150x150) matrix.

Comment: thnks ..Mine does elementary multiplication and not matrix..but I get the error as operands could not broadcast where my dimension is (3x150) *(150x150)...I'm stuck with this error..plz help..

Comment: You cannot do elementwise multiplication unless the sizes match. What do you expect it should do?

Comment: as I mentioned the code works perfectly fine with PCA when fv is of type numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix  and mX(mean centered matrix) as numpy.ndarray.In KPCA its that both fv and  K(Kernel matrix) are of the type numpy.ndarray....I hope this would help you in understanding the problem..

Comment: then use the `numpy.dot`. Presumably these confusions will be gone in 3.5 when we get the `@` op for matrix multiplication; and `*` will be element-wise always.