# Avoiding double for-loops in NumPy array operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

Suppose I have two 2D NumPy arrays `A` and `B`, I would like to compute the matrix `C` whose entries are `C[i, j] = f(A[i, :], B[:, j])`, where `f` is some function that takes two 1D arrays and returns a number.

For instance, if `def f(x, y): return np.sum(x * y)` then I would simply have `C = np.dot(A, B)`. However, for a general function `f`, are there NumPy/SciPy utilities I could exploit that are more efficient than doing a double for-loop?

For example, take `def f(x, y): return np.sum(x != y) / len(x)`, where `x` and `y` are not simply 0/1-bit vectors.

Comment: For that specific case : `np.sum(A[:,None,:] != B.T[None,:,:],axis=2) / A.shape[1]`. It works on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reasonably general approach using broadcasting.

First, reshape your two matrices to be rank-four tensors.

```
A = A.reshape(A.shape + (1, 1))
B = B.reshape((1, 1) + B.shape)
```

Second, apply your function element by element without performing any reduction.

```
C = f(A, B)  # e.g. A != B
```

Having reshaped your matrices allows numpy to [broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html). The resulting tensor `C` has shape `A.shape + B.shape`.

Third, apply any desired reduction by, for example, summing over the indices you want to discard:

```
C = C.sum(axis=(1, 3)) / C.shape[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the generality of the approach! I just have two questions: (1) I'm still not sure what the reduction in the last line do? (2) Suppose both `A` and `B.T` are `n`-by-`d` matrices, is the space complexity for the whole method then `O(n^4 d)`? Would this still be practical when `n` is around say, 10^6?

Comment: (1) Before the reduction, `C` will have shape `(a, b, c, d)` if `A` has shape `(a, b)` and `B` has shape `(c, d)`. So the last step performs the sum you originally mentioned inside the definition of `f`. (2) The space complexity would be `n * n * d * d`. Have a look here for other ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48117449/1150961